# React get specific element in JSX

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs

So I have a jsx like this

```
<img
  onClick={(event) => this.handleImgClick(event)}
  id="typeLightBox"
  className={`${this.state.popupType === 'typeLightBox' ? 'selected' : ''}`}
  src="url"
/>
```

In the className definition I wonder if there is any way I can get the id of this specific img instead of writing the id manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably be to just put it in a variable:

```
const id = "typeLightBox";
return <img
  onClick={(event) => this.handleImgClick(event)}
  id={id}
  className={`${this.state.popupType === id ? 'selected' : ''}`}
  src="url"
/>
```

Comment: yes but this is almost the same thing as typing it manually. However as you say this is the easiest, so I guess there  cannot be any other answer to this question.

Answer (score -1):

> you can use refs
>
> ```
> `<img
>  onClick={(event) => this.handleImgClick(event)}
>  id="typeLightBox"
>  ref={(a) => {this.image = a}}
>  className={`${this.state.popupType === this.image.id ? 'selected' : ''}`}
>  src="url"
> />`
> ```
>
> but you should avoid using refs

Comment: a little bit contradictive